# Error in implementing parallel processing for anomaly detection

Tags: python, parallel-processing, concatenation, valueerror

I have a Python script that reads a dataset, performs anomaly detection for various anomaly types (amount, coa, payee_name) on multiple organizations concurrently using `concurrent.futures`. The script is divided into several functions, and each function is responsible for detecting anomalies of a specific type within an organization.

The error is raised during the concatenation of anomaly DataFrames within the `detect_anomalies_for_org` function, specifically at the line:

```
return pd.concat(anomalies_list)
```

the problem I am facing is:

```
"ValueError: No objects to concatenate"
```

**The code for the parallel processing is below:**

```
result_list = []
    
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_cpus) as executor:
    futures = []
    for Org_id in dataset['Org_id'].unique():
        future = executor.submit(detect_anomalies_for_org, dataset.copy(), Org_id, anomaly_type_sets)
        futures.append(future)
        print(f"Submitted task for Org_id: {Org_id}")
    
    concurrent.futures.wait(futures)
    
    for future in futures:
        result = future.result()
        if not result.empty:
            result_list.append(result)
   
# Concatenate non-empty DataFrames
if result_list:
    merged_anomalies = pd.concat(result_list)
else:
    merged_anomalies = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'Txn_id', 'Org_id', 'Client_id', 'AnomalyType', 'AnomalyScore', 'AnomalyCategory'])
    
# Save the merged anomalies to a CSV file
merged_anomalies.to_csv(output_file_path, index=False)
    
elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
print(f"Execution time: {elapsed_time:.2f} seconds")
```

**The output is as follows:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 246, in _process_worker
    r = call_item.fn(*call_item.args, **call_item.kwargs)
  File "/tmp/ipykernel_10936/3957857038.py", line 177, in detect_anomalies_for_org
    return pd.concat(anomalies_list)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 372, in concat
    op = _Concatenator(
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 429, in __init__
    raise ValueError("No objects to concatenate")
ValueError: No objects to concatenate
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 202
    199 concurrent.futures.wait(futures)
    201 for future in futures:
--> 202     result = future.result()
    203     if not result.empty:
    204         result_list.append(result)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py:451, in Future.result(self, timeout)
    449     raise CancelledError()
    450 elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 451     return self.__get_result()
    453 self._condition.wait(timeout)
    455 if self._state in [CANCELLED, CANCELLED_AND_NOTIFIED]:

File ~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py:403, in Future.__get_result(self)
    401 if self._exception:
    402     try:
--> 403         raise self._exception
    404     finally:
    405         # Break a reference cycle with the exception in self._exception
    406         self = None

ValueError: No objects to concatenate
```

What I've Tried:

- I've verified that the input data (dataset) contains the expected values.
- I've reviewed the anomaly detection logic using Isolation Forest and checked intermediate results.
- I've attempted to handle edge cases where there might be no anomalies.

Comment: Please post your code and output as code-formatted text. Images of code can not be accepted on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I have made the changes hope my question is in the right format, also any idea as how how I can fix it?

Comment: I don´t see the code for the function that is failing. `detect_anomalies_for_org`. Seriously, how do you expect the question to be answered? 

Anyway, what is likely happening is that you are using some global variable to concatenate your dataframes into, and expecting it to exist in the subprocess workers: global variables do exist in the subprocess, but each one will have its own copy.